# Validate single form field only in Symfony2

Tags: validation, symfony

I'm looking for a way to validate just a single field (object property) against the constraints specified in the annotations of a particular entity.

The goal is to send an AJAX request after the "onBlur" event of a form field, asking the server to validate this single field only, and - depending on the response - add a small "OK" image next to this field or an error message.

I don't want to validate the whole entity.

I wonder what's the best approach for this problem? Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `Validator` class has the `validateProperty` method. You can use it like this:

```php
$violations = $this->get('validator')->validateProperty($entity, 'propertyName');
if (count($violations)) {
    // the property value is not valid
}
```

Or, if the value is not set in the entity, you can use the `validatePropertyValue` method:

```php
$violations = $this->get('validator')->validatePropertyValue($entity, 'propertyName', $propertyValue);
if (count($violations)) {
    // the property value is not valid
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/validation.html#validation-groups). I think this is what you need. You could add a group "ajax" or and just adding the one constraint to it. Then tell the validator to use that group. THe symfony2 docs have an example included.